# Class component with conditional table data props

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state, render, react-props

I have a react class component which consists of a table. The table has an edit and delete button that I want to disable if user is not loggedin. I have a isAuthenticated value that I use to check if the user is not logged

Comment: How do you receive `isauthenticated` in `Exercise` component? Is it a part of `props` or coming through some other mean, like a hook or a context?

Comment: Have you try Redux? You can store the isAuthenticated value in redux store and access it in your class component. For more info about redux you can check here https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

There are more than a way to skin this cat. One way is to create a custom component for the links

```tsx
const DisablableLink = ({disabled = false, children, ...rest}) => 
  disabled 
  ? <span style={{color: '#CCCCCC'}}>{children}</span>
  : <Link {...rest} >{children}</Link>
```

This will let you do the following:

1. You can disable the links by passing `disabled` as `true`
2. stylize disabled and enabled component

Here is what your code would look like. (I am assuming `isAuthenticated` coming from the props.

```tsx
const Exercise = props => (

    <tr>
      <td>{props.exercise.username}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.description}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.duration}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.date.substring(0,10)}</td>
      <td>( 
        <DisablableLink disabled={!props.isAuthenticated} to={"/edit/"+props.exercise._id}>edit</DisablableLink> | <DisablableLink disabled={!props.isAuthenticated} onClick={() => { props.deleteExercise(props.exercise._id) }}>delete</DisablableLink>
      ) 
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
```

[I have created a Codesandbox example for you](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-forked-dwckz?file=/index.js)

Comment: I access isAuthenticated through Auth0's high order component, here is the example I used https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react#use-with-a-class-component

Comment: I also modified the code to show the entire file, thank you so much for showing the actual steps in the first example, could you please modify it to work with the way I access isAuthenticated from Auth0?

Comment: Also, if it makes more sense for you to re write my class component as a functional component, feel free, I simply got this file from a tutorial and am trying to build my knowledge of react by adding building on the application.

Comment: You do not show the exercise list when not authenticated. So, what's use of disabling link individually when the whole block won't show up?

Comment: its okay Ive figure it out, but I have another question if you could help, how could I change the exercise lists to only get exercises tied to the specific user that has been authenticated after login? I am assuming I need to set state to force a the component to re render, and make sure I have a condition on the componentdidmount to check for authentication to make the right get call? Your help is very appreciated

Comment: The way it works, usually, you request your back end with authentication token. In your case, JWT. The backend figures out the user and returns only the records that are valid for that user, and you render them. The WRONG way to do the same thing, is to use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the incoming data, and filter out the exercises that does not belong to the logged in user. But a user can easily tweak the JS code to show all with those buttons.

Comment: I get what your saying, I think what I was asking is, can I use componentdidupdate to check if isAuthenticated has turned true and then make an axios get method from that componentdidupdate to check for only the users data? and once I do that, how can I force the "this.exerciseList" in the body to run again with the new updated state of exercises

Comment: Everytime the state is updates, the component rerenders. So, `exerciseLiist` should execute again. But it deserves its own question. They do not cost you a penny. :) Comments are for discussing about the answer provided.